# Error in JavaScript closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal dialog with a submit button, which when clicked caused the following code to execute:

```
$("#addqueuebutton").on("click",function(){

    var counter = 0;
    return function(){
        counter += 1;
        ...
        alert(counter);
    };
});
```

I have to ensure that the `counter` is initialised only once, and so I tried to use a closure. But the code is not executing properly as the alert box does not appear. I tested the code on online compilers and it appears to be correct. Can someone tell me if there is something wrong in my syntax?

Comment: Try to call your function http://jsfiddle.net/xn24as5b/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're assigning the wrong function to `click`. When you click, you initialise `counter` and then return the inner function.

You need to call the outer function and assign its return value to the second argument of `on()`.

`});` should be `}());`

Or, to make it clearer:

```
function create_counter(){
    var counter = 0;

    return function(){
        counter += 1;
        ...
        alert(counter);
    };
}

var counter_incrementing_function = create_counter()

$("#addqueuebutton").on("click", counter_incrementing_function);
```

Comment: OK, you are right. I am using closures for the first time, so let me try to understand this - by using the parenthesis pair, I am calling the outer function. Earlier, was the inner function being called?

Comment: @user3033194 — No. When you click the element it was returned, but a boolean is expected there so it is (effectively) cast to `true` and never called.