# Counter in Javascript closure not incrementing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing some JavaScript code, where I am using a closure for a counter. The code is given below:

```
    function userHandler(){

        var counter = 0;
        var limit = "<?php echo ($_SESSION['limit']); ?>";

        return function(){
            var args = {

                n : $('#name').val(),
                s : $('#ssn').val(),
                i : $('#id').val()

            };

            $.post("adduser.php",args,function(data){  
                var response = JSON.parse(data);  
                console.log(args);  
                if(response.status == 0){
                    counter += 1;
                    alert(counter);
                    if (counter == limit){

                        $('#limit').text(limit-counter);

                    }
                }
                console.log(data);      
            });
        };
}

var opcall = userHandler();

$('#addUser').on("click", opcall);
```

I am using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504463/error-in-javascript-closure) to write the code. The problem is, my counter always shows 1 in the alert box. It does not increment. Am I not calling the inner method correctly?

EDIT: There's a span in the HTML which is receiving the limit-counter value:

```
<p>
    <span>Add User</span>
    You can add <span id="limit"></span> more users. <a href='<?php echo $root; ?>editaccount.php?action=addOp'>Add another operator?</a>
</p>
```

It always shows (20-1)=19 every time I submit the form which uses the Javascript.

UPDATE: Thank you for pointing out my mistake, after clicking the "addUser" button, another page was opening with a confirmation message, where a link had to be clicked to return to the original page. I moved the confirmation message to the original page and now it works fine!!

Comment: Are you adding the value of counter back into the DOM at some point? If so where?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cmc4zhf6/1/ - looks fine

Comment: @atmd: It's only once if you click `#addUser` once. If you click it twice it runs twice.

Comment: What is `#addUser`? A div? A link?

Comment: your counter variable may be always reinitialized and set to zero every time when it is called  .

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara: Every time the `opcall` function is called?

Comment: Can you make sure that the page is not reloading ?

Comment: @slebetman i mean function with return statement

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara: I mean you misunderstand the code. `userHandler()` is only called once and its purpose is to create the `opcall` function. It's the `opcall` function that gets called multiple times each time you click `#addUser`

Comment: @slebetman adduser is a button.

Comment: Aha. So my real question is actually @Hacketo's question: are you sure the button isn't causing the page to reload (thereby destroying all your js variables and creating brand new ones)? Make sure you've done your preventDefault

Comment: @slebetman - maybe I should define the function as userHandler(event), and then write event.preventDefault(). But then should var opcall = userHandler(event)? I'll try it

Comment: No. It's opcall that should accept the event object (which isn't created until the button is pressed so it doesn't exist when you call `userHandler()`). Basically you need to `return function (event) {...`

Comment: Also, if you care about people who use IE8 and below, you also need to check if the event object is passed as the first argument or as a global variable called `window.event`